# Shopware 6 Administration Service Giving 'UNDEFINED' error

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I created a Shopware 6 administration service but it doesn't seem to work. I get an `undefined` error or error `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getString')`.

```js
//<administration root>core/service/ai.service.js 
export default class AIService {
    constructor(httpClient) {
        this.httpClient = httpClient;
    }

    getString() {
        return 'hello';
    }
}
```

I initialized the service this way

```js
///init/ai-service.init.js
import AIService from '../core/service/ai.service'

Shopware.Service().register('ai', (container) => {
    const initContainer = Shopware.Application.getContainer('init');
    return new AIService(initContainer.httpClient);
});
```

And finally, I injected it into my Vue component

```js
Shopware.Component.register('example', {
    inject: ['ai'],

    created() {
        this.ai.getString().then(value => console.log(value))
    }
});
```

I get the error error `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getString')`

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution:

```
async created() {
        await this.ai.getString().then(value => console.log(value))
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).